# Build flutter project on mac m1. A error hint me that : "Error: To set up CocoaPods for ARM macOS, run: arch -x86_64 sudo gem install ffi"

Tags: flutter, macos, apple-m1

I run the code  arch -x86_64 sudo gem install ffi; But while I build the project again, it still notice me that

> Error: To set up CocoaPods for ARM macOS, run:
> arch -x86_64 sudo gem install ffi
>
> Error running pod install
>
> Error launching application on iPhone 13.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac M1 system you can follow below steps.

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
sudo gem install ffi
arch -x86_64 sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin
sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin
```